# Subquery with WHERE NOT IN not filtering data as expected

Tags: sql-server, subquery, where-in

I have a sub-query that works standalone but when used as a filter seems to do nothing.

My data contains no NULLs. I can run the sub-query and get the count of customers I expect (customers that have PIDs like %CLUSTER%) but when I run the full query, the WHERE NOT IN clause doesn't seem to filter out the customers the sub-query selects.

```
SELECT PID, ROUND(SUM(bookings),0) AS Bookings
FROM d_bookings
WHERE GU_Name NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(GU_NAME)
    FROM d_bookings 
    WHERE PID LIKE '%CLUSTER%'
    AND Sales_Level_1 IN (
    'GLOBAL SERVICE PROVIDER'
    ,'APJC__'
    ,'EMEAR-REGION'
    ,'AMERICAS'
    ,'CORP ADJUSTMENT'
    )
    AND Corp_Bookings = 'Y'
)
GROUP BY PID
ORDER BY Bookings DESC;
```

The result should not contain any PIDs like %CLUSTER%. In English, I want a total bookings for all PIDs sold to customers that did not purchase a cluster. The sub-query makes a list of customers that DID buy a cluster and I'm trying to exclude those customers from the result.

Here is a sample table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpbook;
CREATE TABLE tmpbook ("FYQ" char(10), "gu_name" char(10),"PID" char(20), "bookings" numeric);
INSERT INTO tmpbook
    VALUES 
        ('FY2019Q1', 'Company1','CLUSTER1',12345.67),
        ('FY2019Q1', 'Company1','SOMETHINGELSE',2345.67),
        ('FY2019Q1', 'Company2','CLUSTER2',345.67),
        ('FY2019Q1', 'Company2','SOMETHINGELSE',12345.67),
        ('FY2019Q1', 'Company3','SOMETHINGELSE',2345.67),
        ('FY2019Q1', 'Company3','SOMETHINGELSE',345.67) 
;
```

The expected result will be 
NOTACLUSTER 2691.34 (2345.67 + 345.67)

because only Company3 did not buy a cluster (should exclude Company1 and Company2 because they DID buy a cluster.

Comment: can you please add some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having two issues. 1 - my data was messed up. 2 - my subquery an main query needed the same constraints.

```
SELECT PID, ROUND(SUM(BOOKINGS),0) AS BOOKINGS
FROM d_bookings
WHERE GU_Name NOT IN (
    SELECT GU_NAME
    FROM d_bookings
    WHERE PID LIKE '%CLUSTER%'
    AND Sales_Level_1 IN (
    'GLOBAL SERVICE PROVIDER'
    ,'APJC__'
    ,'EMEAR-REGION'
    ,'AMERICAS'
    ,'CORP ADJUSTMENT'
    )
    AND Corp_Bookings = 'Y')
AND Sales_Level_1 IN (
    'GLOBAL SERVICE PROVIDER'
    ,'APJC__'
    ,'EMEAR-REGION'
    ,'AMERICAS'
    ,'CORP ADJUSTMENT'
    )
AND Corp_Bookings = 'Y'
GROUP BY PID
ORDER BY BOOKINGS DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the your query should give you empty result. as the condition WHERE PID LIKE '%CLUSTER%' is true for both types of record.

e.g.

```
'Cluster1' LIKE '%CLUSTER%' --is  true

'NotACluster' LIKE '%CLUSTER%' --is  true
```

so if u want o fiter out only records like 'Cluster1','Cluster1', etc. then the condition should look like

`PID LIKE 'Cluster%'`

Comment: Sorry about the mistake in the example - edited it to better capture the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the rest of the WHERE clause in the subquery should be on the main query:

```
SELECT PID, ROUND(SUM(bookings),0) AS Bookings
FROM d_bookings
WHERE GU_Name NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(GU_NAME)
    FROM d_bookings 
    WHERE PID LIKE '%CLUSTER%'
    )
    AND Corp_Bookings = 'Y'
    AND Sales_Level_1 IN (
    'GLOBAL SERVICE PROVIDER'
    ,'APJC__'
    ,'EMEAR-REGION'
    ,'AMERICAS'
    ,'CORP ADJUSTMENT'
)
GROUP BY PID
ORDER BY Bookings DESC;
```

But if that's true, you should be able to replace the subquery with a NOT LIKE, instead:

```
SELECT PID, ROUND(SUM(bookings),0) AS Bookings
FROM d_bookings
WHERE PID NOT LIKE '%CLUSTER%'
    AND Corp_Bookings = 'Y'
    AND Sales_Level_1 IN (
    'GLOBAL SERVICE PROVIDER'
    ,'APJC__'
    ,'EMEAR-REGION'
    ,'AMERICAS'
    ,'CORP ADJUSTMENT'
    )
GROUP BY PID
ORDER BY Bookings DESC;
```